# How will the image of upper half plane $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$ be under the LFT $w=\frac{3z+i}{-iz+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I find

1. The image of the upper half plane $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$ under the linear fractional transformation $w=\dfrac{3z + i}{-iz + 1}$.
2. The image of the set {${z∈C-0:\{\mathrm{Im}(z)} = \mathrm{Re}(z)\}$} under $w=z + \dfrac{1}{z}$.

For 1.,
I consider $y>0, x \in R$ and then find the inverse $z=\dfrac{w-i}{3+iw}$. This gave me $x=\dfrac{2u}{{(3-v)}^2+u^2}$ and $y=\dfrac{-v^2-u^2+4v-3}{(3-v)^2+u^2}$. Then since $y>0$, 
${-v^2-u^2+4v-3}>0$ which gave me ${(v-2)}^2+u^2<1$.
I therefore knew that the image is the interior of the unit disk centered at $(0,2)$ and drew it. So I need confirmation.
But for the second one, I am confused as how the image should be because if $\text{Im}(z)=\text{Re}(z)$ and $w=z+\dfrac{1}{z}$, then $z$ should not be $0$, but I thought the the line $\text{Im}(z)=\text{Re}(z)$ must pass through the origin. I am waiting for help!

Comment: And for mathematical typing, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)

Comment: For the second part, the map is well defined if you're working on the Riemann sphere, but that is only relevant if you've been introduced to it. If not, perhaps you're still expected to only work with the upper half plane as the domain?

Comment: Hello Daniel Rust. I am not introduced to Riemann sphere and so it's irrelevant to me as you said, however, the question does not stated to work only with the upper half plane, rather the set $C-0$(I mean the set of complex numbers excluding  $0$). So what should I do?

Comment: Any one to help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice job on the first part. For the second part, note that we're considering the set $$\left\{z\in\Bbb C-0:\text{Re}(z)=\text{Im}(z)\right\},$$ and **not** the set $$\left\{z\in\Bbb C:\text{Re}(z)=\text{Im}(z)\right\},$$ so we don't have to worry about $z=0$. Now, suppose $z$ is in this set, meaning $z=(1+i)t$ for some non-zero real $t$. Then $$w=z+\frac1z=z+\frac{\overline z}{|z|^2}=(1+i)t+\frac{(1-i)t}{2t^2}=\frac{2t^2+1}{2t}+i\frac{2t^2-1}{2t}.$$ We *could* express the image as the set of points of the above form, but that isn't very revealing.

Instead, note that if $w=u+iv$ has the above form, then $u+v=2t$ and $u-v=\frac1t,$ so $u^2-v^2=2$. Conversely, if $u^2-v^2=2$ with $u,v$ real then $u\ne v$ and $$\frac{u+v}2=\frac1{u-v}.$$ Putting $t:=u-v,$ then, we have that $t$ is non-zero real, and putting $z=(1+i)t$, we have $w=z+\frac1z,$ as desired. Thus, our image is the hyperbola $$\left\{w:\bigl(\text{Re}(w)\bigr)^2-\bigl(\text{Im}(w)\bigr)^2=2\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you Cameron Buie. I think this will help a lot, however, you will soon see my reply. Thanks once more.

Comment: Hi Cameron Buie, am back.
I discovered a similar problem that I want to ask, it says:
Describe the set ${z∈C-0:\{\mathrm({1-i})zconj+({1+i})z = 0}$ and it's image under $w=z + \dfrac{1}{z}$. (I mean $z$ conjugate by $zconj$). I evaluated the set and it turned out to be the same set $Im{z}=Re{z}$. Am I right?

Comment: Is that what they mean by "Describe the set"?

Comment: You are correct that those two sets are the same. "Describe the set" typically means to give the best verbal description of the set that you can--rather than just set-builder notation. For example, you might further describe the hyperbola by giving its vertices, foci, asymptotes, *etc.*

Comment: Okay. Thank you Cameron Buie, I have fully understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way for part one (we can use geometry view):

First, note that $$w=B(z)=\dfrac{3z + i}{-iz + 1}=3i+\frac{2}{z+i}$$

So we can write $B$ as $B(z)=B_4\circ B_3 \circ  B_2\circ B_1(z)$ where $B_1(z)=z+i$ translation for $i$, $B_2(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$ inversion function, $B_3(z)=2z$ homotety with index $2$ and $B_4(z)=z+3i$ translation for $3i$.

Now, first $B_1(\mathbb{H})=\mathbb{H}_1$ where $\mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{\mathfrak{Im}}(z)>0 \}$ and $\mathbb{H}_1=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{\mathfrak{Im}}(z)>1 \}.$ Then $B_2(\mathbb{H}_1)=\mathbb{D}_1$ where $\mathbb{D}_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \left|z+\frac{i}{2}\right|<\frac{1}{2}\}$ (we can see this because $B_2(\infty)=0, B_2(i)=-i$ and $B_2(2i)=-\dfrac{i}{2}$ (this third one to see its exterior or interior of disc)), then $B_3(\mathbb{D}_1)=\mathbb{D}_2$ where $\mathbb{D}_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \left|z+i\right|<1\}$ and then $B_4(\mathbb{D}_2)=\mathbb{D}_3$ where $\mathbb{D}_3 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \left|z-2i\right|<1\}.$

So $B(\mathbb{H})=\mathbb{D}_3.$

Comment: Cortizol I think this is great also! I didn't think of it in that sense. Thanks.

Comment: @YYG I'm glad to hear that.